# Take address of value inside an interface

Tags: pointers, interface, go, memory-address

How do I take the address of a value inside an interface?

I have an struct stored in an interface, in a list.List element:

```
import "container/list"
type retry struct{}
p := &el.Value.(retry)
```

But I get this:

```
cannot take the address of el.Value.(retry)
```

What's going on? Since the struct is stored in the interface, why can't I get a pointer to it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To understand why this isn't possible, it is helpful to think about what an interface variable actually is.  An interface value takes up two words, with the first describing the type of the contained value, and the second either (a) holding the contained value (if it fits within the word) or (b) a pointer to storage for the value (if the value does not fit within a word).

The important things to note are that (1) the contained value belongs to the interface variable, and (2) the storage for that value may be reused when a new value is assigned to the variable.  Knowing that, consider the following code:

```
var v interface{}
v = int(42)
p := GetPointerToInterfaceValue(&v) // a pointer to an integer holding 42
v = &SomeStruct{...}
```

Now the storage for the integer has been reused to hold a pointer, and `*p` is now an integer representation of that pointer.  You can see how this has the capacity to break the type system, so Go doesn't provide a way to do this (outside of using the `unsafe` package).

If you need a pointer to the structs you're storing in a list, then one option would be to store pointers to the structs in the list rather than struct values directly.  Alternatively, you could pass `*list.Element` values as references to the contained structures.

Comment: This seems far more reasonable. I think it's enough to say that you can't make any guarantees about the contained value's storage is sufficient.

Comment: On second thought I don't see any circumstance in which inlining the interface storage with the interface could be resized without relocating the interface.

Comment: Well, I gave a case when the storage used for the interface's value is reused.  Since the language doesn't guarantee that the storage won't be reused, it makes sense not to give you a typed pointer to that storage.  And since interface values store larger values in separately allocated memory (using the second word as a pointer to that storage), you will be using the same amount of memory by storing `*retry` values in your list instead.

Answer (score 2):

A type assertion is an expression that results in two values. Taking the address in this case would be ambiguous.

```
p, ok := el.Value.(retry)
if ok {
    // type assertion successful
    // now we can take the address
    q := &p 
}
```

From the comments:

> Note that this is a pointer to a copy of the value rather than a pointer to the value itself.
>
> — [James Henstridge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/721283/james-henstridge)

The solution to the problem is therefore simple; store a pointer in the interface, not a value.

Comment: Note that this is a pointer to a copy of the value rather than a pointer to the value itself.

Comment: This is unreasonable. Of course I have got a copy after assigning to as the automatic variable `p`. But while it's still an rvalue I should be able to take the address of the value as it is stored inside the interface. Since the interface is stored inline in `Value`, it's fair to assume the value _inside the interface_ is heap-allocated, and therefore can be modified in place.

Comment: @MattJoiner: Large values contained by an interface indeed are heap allocated. But the pointer to the value is a non specified, non exposed implementation detail (wrt the language per se and modulo technics I cannot recomend to use). If you need a pointer _from_ an interface then put a pointer _into_ the interface.

Answer (score 2):

> [Get pointer to interface value?](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/vPHiJwxVN98/discussion)
>
> Is there a way, given a variable of interface type, of getting a
>   pointer to the value stored in the variable?
>
> It is not possible.
>
> Rob Pike

Interface values are not necessarily addressable. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i interface{}
    i = 42
    // cannot take the address of i.(int)
    j := &i.(int)
    fmt.Println(i, j)
}
```

> [Address operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)
>
> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a
>   pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is,
>   either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation;
>   or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array
>   indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the
>   addressability requirement, x may also be a composite literal.

References:

[Interface types](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

[Type assertions](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)

[Go Data Structures: Interfaces](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

[Go Interfaces](http://www.airs.com/blog/archives/277)

Answer (score 1):

In the first approximation: You cannot do that. Even if you could, `p` itself would the have to have type `interface{}` and would not be too helpful - you cannot directly dereference it then.

The obligatory question is: What problem are you trying to solve?

And last but not least: Interfaces define behavior not structure. Using the interface's underlying implementing type directly in general breaks the interface contract, although there might be non general legitimate cases for it. But those are already served, for a finite set of statically known types, by the [type switch statement](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements).

Comment: I don't see why this is necessary. After the type assertion, I should be able to take the address of the value pointed to by what should amount to an rvalue reference returned from the interface.

Comment: @MattJoiner: If the value contained in the interface is not a pointer type, then the type assertion provides a copy. But your question is titled: _"Take address of value __inside__ an interface"_. (emphasizes mine). IOW, if you want a pointer to the original, non pointer type that was put in the interface, type assertion won't help as the interface internally carries only a pointer to such instance (modulo small values fitting in a machine word). Why don't you simply put a pointer to a value inside the interface? Then you get directly what you are after in a language supported way.