# How to get the underlying value of pointer type in Go?

Tags: go, pointers

I found this question [How to get a pointer to the underlying value of an Interface{} in Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57696977/how-to-get-a-pointer-to-the-underlying-value-of-an-interface-in-go), but it looks too unsafe for me.

Of course I could use `*` to unpack it but I have to add nil check every time on caller side.

```golang
x := &some_type
fmt.Println(*x)
```

I am expecting the function that return default value of the base type if the pointer is nil.

```golang
x := Unpacker(some_type)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd just check for `nil` with an if statement. It's the reasonable thing to do. Though if you want to explore alternatives, read on.

In Go 1.18 you can accomplish this with a simple generic function:

```
func val[T any](v *T) T {
    if v != nil {
        return *v
    }
    return *new(T) // zero value of T
}
```

However this works only for pointer types in the form `*T`. There's other types in Go which have `nil` as zero value and are not pointers. Or this function could still return `nil` if you pass a pointer to such a type, like `*[]int`. Unfortunately there isn't a handy way to declare a constraint for all possible nillable types<sup>1</sup>.

With Go 1.17 and below you can use a type switch if the set of possible types is known, but then have to assert the result. This has the minor advantage of permitting ad-hoc initialization of nillable types:

```
func val(v interface{}) interface{} {
    switch t := v.(type) {
    case *string:
        if t != nil {
            return *t
        }
        return ""

    case *[]string:
        if t != nil {
            return *t
        }
        return []string{}

    default:
        panic("unexpected type")
    }
}
```

Or just use reflection, with the same limitations of having to assert the return, or risking to return `nil` again:

```
func val(v interface{}) interface{} {
    t := reflect.TypeOf(v)
    if t == nil || t.Kind() != reflect.Ptr {
        panic("invalid input")
    }
    rv := reflect.ValueOf(v)
    if rv.IsNil() {
        return reflect.Zero(rv.Type().Elem()).Interface()
    }
    return v
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/9dk0hWay90j

---

1: mainly because such a constraint would have to capture the key and/or value types of the map type, and decide what to (arbitrarily) return in those cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am accepting another answer, but here is what I tried which apparently work for primitives too.

```
func Unwrap[T any](x *T) (r T) {
    if x != nil {
        r = *x
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is functionally equivalent to the first snippet in my answer. The main difference is only in how the zero value for `T` is obtained. In this case with a named return type, in my case with a an explicit `*new(T)`